# "Is used" vs. "has been used" vs. "was used"

Tags: grammaticality, past-tense, present-perfect, present-tense, simple-past

I have three sentences of which I'm not sure which one is grammatical, and why.

*It* refers to the Eiffel Tower.

> - It **is used** as the symbol of Paris and of France for over a century.
> - It **was used** as the symbol of Paris and of France for over a century.
> - It **has been used** as the symbol of Paris and of France for over a century.

Comment: *"It is used":* wrong—if you include *"for over a century",* you need to use a past tense. *"It was used":* wrong—this implies that it is not currently used. *"It has been used":* correct.

Answer (score 8):

*It **has been used** as the symbol...* is correct here. Use [Present Perfect](http://www.englishservicesforscientists.com/1/post/2012/06/grammar-guide-3-simple-past-vs-present-perfect.html) when the action referred to started in the past, and either continues (or *continues to have relevance*) at the time of speaking.

Answer (score 4):

"It has been used", because it's still "used as the symbol of Paris and of France".